Finding the matrix of a transformation
I’m given the linear transformation $$T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R};\ T \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{x+y}{2},$$ and I’m asked to obtain the matrix representation with respect to the bases $\alpha=\big((1,1),(2,3)\big)$ and $\beta=(5)$.
I know in general I’m supposed to obtain the images of elements of the basis under the transformation and express them in terms of the elements of the basis of the target space.
In this case, we have
$$
T\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)5\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ T\begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 3 \end{pmatrix}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)5
$$
giving $M(T)= \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{5} & \dfrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$. However, $$\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{5} & \dfrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =\dfrac{7}{10}\not=\dfrac{1}{5} \ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \   \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{5} & \dfrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 3 \end{pmatrix} =\dfrac{17}{10}\not=\dfrac{1}{2}.$$ What am I missing/doing wrong?

Let the basis elements be $b_1,b_2$, then $T(b_1) = {1 \over 5} 5$ and $T(b_2) = {1 \over 2} 5$ and so the matrix representation is $M=[{1 \over 5} \ {1 \over 2}]$. In order to compute $T(b_1)$ you need to find the representation of $b_1$ in terms of the basis, and it is $e_1$ , so $M e_1 = {1 \over 5}$ as you had hoped.

Point being that $M$ does not operate on the original basis but on the representation of the point in terms of the basis.

As you put $\pmatrix{\frac15}$ as column 1, and $\pmatrix{\frac12}$ as column 2 of $M$, you are considering $\pmatrix{\frac15} = M\pmatrix{1\0}$ and $\pmatrix{\frac12} = M\pmatrix{0\1}$.

You did well, but you must multiply coordinate vector corresponding to your ordered basis.
(Do not multiply vector which respect to standard basis directly!)
For example,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}=1\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix} + 0\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
3 
\end{pmatrix}$$
So, coordinate vector of $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}$ respect to basis $\alpha$ is $(1, 0)$.
Then,
$$
M\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}= \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)
$$
is also coordinate vector of $\beta$, your result is $\frac{1}{5}\times 5 = 1$ as you desired.
